# Javascript when button onclick change element position

Tags: javascript, html, button, position, element

I'm trying to do a button that when clicked will change my div position, I already do this:

```js
function myFunctionkomp1()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top="300px";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionkomp1();" id="btnmenukomp"></button>
<div class="MyDiv" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

And it works, but the only problem is that when I will click a second time on it the margin top will go to 0 (default).

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunctionkomp1()
{
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top == '300px'){
        document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top="0px";    
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top="300px";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code of how to do it, but a good approach would be to do a "toggle" that alters between top=0px and top=300px. That way the 1st click with go to top =300px, 2nd click will go to top=0px, 3rd click will go back to 300px, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add some kind of toggle functionality. Eg:

```
var top = document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top;
top = top === '300px' ? 0 : '300px';
document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top = top;
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ubL3hx2w/

Answer (score -1):

You need a toggle variable like this (there are shorter ways to do this but in order to illustrate what the code is doing I have written it this way:

```
<script>
var toggle=true;
function myFunctionkomp1()
{
    if(flip) { 
        document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.top="300px";
        toggle=false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].style.marginTop="0px";
        toggle=true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Due to his poor english I misread it. @MrLister I was currently editing my answer.